# how can i export 3d object from illustrator to photoshop to paint it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d

i have 3d object i want to take it to photoshop to paint but keep it 3d. What can i do.  I have done dragging it. But it dosent help. Exporting from illustrator still causes it to be either vector or jpg/png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**

Illustrator offers no support for actual 3D models - neither importing them nor exporting them.

Comment: maybe there is a plugin...